# Video lectures for Complex Geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, online-resources

Does anyone know the video lectures of a Complex Geometry course which are freely available online? I aim to understand the book lectures on K3 surfaces by Daniel Huybrechts afterward.

Comment: Short answer (for me): No. <> It's probably a good idea to say something about your background and aims, however, since there are many disparate paths to complex geometry (differential geometry, several complex variables, algebraic geometry, physics, ...), and maybe also what books you've attempted to read and what about them was deficient for you.

Comment: I have studied Differential Geometry, Algebraic Geometry, Complex Analysis. My aim for studying Complex Geometry is to understand the book Lectures on K3 surfaces by Daniel Huybrechts.

Comment: So, when you start reading Huybrechts's book (which I do not personally know), what things do you stumble over that you do not know?

Comment: Kahler manifolds and Hodge theory. Do you know any textbooks on K3 surfaces in which complex geometry's prerequisites are discussed sufficiently?

Comment: Huybrechts has another book (“Complex geometry”) that covers the basics of Kahler manifolds and Hodge theory. It’s very good. I think books on K3 surfaces, or any non-introductory topic, assume the reader knows the basics.

Answer (score 2):

[Complex Algebraic Geometry](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Epalbin/Math514.Fall2020/home.html) is the Best I can find

Comment: Hi, thank you very much!

Comment: @Ajay Thanks, this is a great series of lectures. The intro to the lecture on Kodaira vanishing is unfortunately very awkward XD.